# CSS resize property behavior when used with flex-wrap

Tags: css

I'm currently working into a project with ReactJS and TailwindCSS where I'm making sort of a "grid" of resizable textareas and the behavior is almost how I want, except when i resize any element on the right side of the screen, which causes it to break to next line due of `flex-wrap` and then the resize I was doing gets recalculated taking into consideration that the textarea and the mouse positions are different than before (this is the problem).

I want to know if it's possible to make it work in the way I'm going and would be really helpfull any tip or workaround at it.

```
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

.container{
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

textarea {
  resize: both;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/FHPB/pen/poZByWb) with an example (written in HTML and  CSS).

Here is an image that illustrates the textarea while resizing

[image: Image of the div while resizing]

This is what happens when the resize exceeds the flex limit and the wrap happens

[image]

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself. This is a requirement for the site for debugging questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you want to do?

```
<div class="up_container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="down_container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

.up_container,
.down_container {
  min-height: 50vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  gap: 10px;
}

textarea {
  resize: both;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: No, i want the element to go to next row (dividing it is not an option because in my real scenario i'm looping trought elements and rendering textareas dinamically), imagine it like a gallery of textareas. The problem is that when i resize the textarea more on the right it gets stretched in the next line, instead of the size i was intending it to be

Answer (score 0):

you must define a width to your container and a min-height to your textarea. I think that's what you want?

```
.container{
  width:200vh;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

textarea {
  resize: both;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  max-height: 400px;
  max-width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: This wont solve it. Imagine that i resized the textarea to be 350 px in height, then when it breaks to the next line it will be 200px in height. I want somehow a workaround to mantain the size when it breaks to the next line (no need to keep the CSS i did tho, any workaround is okay for me). Also the textarea must have a height set otherwise all textareas will be resized together when div grows.

Comment: when the container goes to line, its the new height is equivalent to (the old height (top line)) - (your gap) - (the height of the remaining containers)... I see no solutions on flexible, if you never get there I'm a taker.... ;) good luck

Comment: If not with flex do u see any other kind of solution? I tho grid also would not work due of the nature of keeping elements into row/column, which would make the resize a problem

Comment: the problem is that the space of the container keeps the size before the line break, so it reduces the height of the container that goes to the line according to the calculation explained previously.... I don't see a way to force that ....Otherwise you play on the font size according to the size of the container with the media queries...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).